# What to do with escaped unicode characters when calling JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json

I have some strings that I am writing out as JSON. One of the strings contains the character `\u001a`. Calling `JSON.parse('"\u001a"')` results in `JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`. What am I supposed to do about this character?

Thanks!

Comment: `JSON.parse('"\\u001a"')`

Answer (score 0):

Probably using `\\` instead of `\` can solve the problem.

First snippet will alert exception and parse result as `undefined` bec. of parse error.

```js
try {
    var x = JSON.parse('"\u001a"');
} catch (e) {
    alert('Catched exception: ' + e);
} finally {
    alert('Parsed value: ' + x);
}
```

The second one alert parsed sequence. That means that parsing is successful.

```js
var z = JSON.parse('"\\u001a"');
alert(z);
```